# WordPress widget title using different background image?

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I want to use a different background image for each title () that is generated by the widget in my WordPress theme. Which widgets added to the sidebar are optional? Is there a way to get this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the_title() from your template for the article titled "foo", add #title_foo to the CSS style (using [the_title_attribute()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_title_attribute)) and then change the background for that ID in your CSS.